# Sending SMS to data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

We work on a new SFMC org and we would like to send SMS directly to a Data Extension as it is now possible.

However, should we import first the mobile number (with the Locale and the ContactKey) in MobileConnect for the SMS send to work?

Also is the creation of keywords (other than the Help and Stop ones) compulsory for a SMS send ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You don't need to import contacts to AllContacts Mobile if you are sending to a Data Extension.

Contacts in the Data Extension with valid data will be added to AllContacts Mobile automatically.

Please note that:

> You can send only to data extensions that are marked as **sendable** and
>   that **contain** one **phone field** and one **locale field**. Mobile numbers used
>   in the data extension **must be normalized** during the imports process.

**Reference:**

[Send a Message to a Data Extension](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_june_2018_moc_send_to_data_extension.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you pick under "Opt-in Certification".

There two options

1. Confirm Subscriber Opt-in

- Import: Yes, you will need to import the contacts before you send.
- Keywords: No
- You can still send SMS, but only the contacts are already in MobileConnect will get the SMS.

2. Subscribe all contacts to a keyword

- Import: No, you won't need to import first. MobileConnect will add your contacts and associate it to the Keyword
- Keywords: This option make creating a keyword compulsory